# How to realize open formula in Coq?

Tags: coq

How to realize open formula in Coq?
I think Coq's `Prop` means closed formula,
but I also want to use open formula such as `x = 0`.
If anything, `x` is in `R`.

```
Check x = 0.
(* The reference x was not found in the current environment. *)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could define an arbitrary variable x without instantiating it, such as:

`Variable x:nat.
Check x = 0.`

Answer (score 1):

"open" formulas don't make sense either in Coq or in pen-and-paper logic unless you have an environment to interpret variables. `Check term` requires indeed a closed term so you'll have to specify a binding for `x`, for example `exists x, x = 0`.